# java.security.AccessControlException on XSD validation with SAX Parser

Tags: java, google-app-engine, accesscontrolexception

I have written an SAX parser in my Google App Engine Web application. in that I try to validate my xml file with an xsd. But I am getting an access control exception when my code is tyring to access that xsd.

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission \WEB-INF\ApplicationResponse.xsd read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:264)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:427)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:100)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.xsdToXMLInputSource(XMLSchemaLoader.java:830)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.processJAXPSchemaSource(XMLSchemaLoader.java:708)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:554)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2459)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:330)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:779)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1794)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:834)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1242)
    at sax.SAXLocalNameCount.parse(SAXLocalNameCount.java:220)
    at com.sms2mint.InterfaceServlet.doGet(InterfaceServlet.java:54)`

Please let me know how to debug this?
I have tried to place the xsd in classes, webcontent, /WEB-INF but didn't help. Also declared this as a resource file in appengine-web.xml also but no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

The FileInputStream should be a white-listed reader function.  Are you having this access problem in the development environment (in which case what is your development environment? There have been reports of similar issues with people using the Eclipse plugin that resolved after restarting eclipse, cleaning, and re-building the project), or in a deployed application?

How are you specifying the path to your file? Can you include code?

Comment: Hi Bosh, actually it is not a problem with google app engine but the way I was trying to access a resource. I was trying to access a file in the webContent directory directly. I used getResourceAsStream and it is working now. Thank you.